# How to add a Pie Chart using another data source from main report data source

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset, datasource, pie-chart

I want to add below of my report a pie chart that uses another data source from reports main data. I'm trying to add another source on my dataset but Crystal has a mechanism that linking  relational fields, and if i link them rows are repeating on report and if i don't link then no data appearing on report. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crystal reports, you can add subreport and one dataset with many datatable (main report data and pie chart data). 
Right click on main report, insert subreport. Choose another datasource from main report. Clean all report items and add pie chart to this subreport using the datasource.
Its OK.

Comment: Voila.. Thank you birdort, it's a really great touch and a quick solution with my luck :)